# Python need third quote style for '<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> index </a>'

Tags: python

Simple question but I never had this issue and right now I am really puzzled.

For my flask google maps function I need to set an infobox which should be clickable and redirects the user to the room which has been clicked.

For this I use:

```
infobox=['<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> index </a>'], etc.
```

But it wont validate because these quotes `""` `''` are not enough to cover the expression.

**EDIT**

This is the piece of code which creates the map:

```
    if location.latitude is not None:
        mymap = Map(
        identifier="view-side",
        lat=location.latitude,
        lng=location.longitude,
        infobox=['''<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> index </a>'''],
        markers=[],
        zoom = 12
        )
    else:
        print "location is none"
```

If I use `\'` it already fails in the .py to read it properly (I have not copy/pasted):

[image]

The tripple `"""` do not work aswell because they are translated back in javascript to single `"`:

[image]

**EDIT**

That is the full example of what I need to include:

```
mymap.infobox.append(r'''<a href=\"{{ url_for('room_details', the_room_id=zimmer.id) }}\"><img src="../static/userimg/{{ zimmer.hauptbild }}" width=80 height=55 /></a>\\''')
```

Comment: If you want to generate correct javascript, use this: `infobox=[r'''<a href=\"{{ url_for('index') }}\"> index </a>\\']`

Comment: This seems to work, but I have to try out with a more complex version, I also need to include an image, but looks promising.

Comment: Now that I think about it, your safest bet is to use `json.dumps` to print a properly escaped javascript string. That will take care of adding a literal backslash before the quotes.

Comment: That actually was my simple version of it, check my update what I need to include...

Comment: I read your update. You need a combination of using triple-quotes or escaping, as in my answer, and then when rendering the infobox to Javascript, use `json.dumps` to turn it into a JSON/Javascript string, which will properly escape the quotes, thus creating a string that represents valid HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply asking how to escape the apostrophes you want to include your string, then this should work:

```
infobox=['<a href="{{ url_for(\'index\') }}"> index </a>']
```

Alternatively, with python, you can also use three apostrophes or quotes to enable easier input of strings:

```
infobox=['''<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> index </a>''']
```

Comment: +1 for the triple-quote method. Personally, I find that a lot easier to use when I expect to be putting quotes in my strings.

Comment: Sadly both of them do not work, its a bit tricky because the expression is used by google`s javascript later to create this infobox. I`ll specify the question

Comment: @Roman, btw, single-quotes (`'`), rather than backticks (`\``), should be used for English text.